# Test Django user profile one-to-one link

Tags: django, testing

I'm adding a Profile to my Django app as a way to store more User information. Following https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

However I'm getting an error when testing it. I'm using the default User model from `django.contrib.auth`.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver    


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

tests/test_model.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import Profile


class ProfileModelTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Profile.objects.create()

    def test_can_create_profile(self):
        pass
```

error

```
/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
..........E............
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (project-api.polls.tests.test_models.ProfileModelTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (158, null).


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1002, in setUpClass
    cls.setUpTestData()
  File "/Users/user/programming/gatsby/project-api/polls/tests/test_models.py", line 86, in setUpTestData
    Profile.objects.create()
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1283, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-api-HgI9cQzm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (158, null).


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 2.198s

FAILED (errors=1)
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Preserving test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
```

With this code, you are listening to the save method of the `User` model to create a related `Profile` entry *just in time*, if there isn't one yet. This way, you can just go along creating new Users without worrying at creating and linking Profiles manually everytime.

Note that the reverse isn't covered: if you want to create a Profile entry directly, you **must** pass an existing User object to it, or else you will get an `IntegrityError`.

Solution: preferrably, stick to one main way to create user + profile pairs; in your case, just create a User and let the signal call the creation of the profile automatically.

```
class ProfileModelTests(TestCase):                                                                                        
    @classmethod                                                                                                          
    def setUpTestData(cls):                                                                                               
        get_user_model().objects.create()                                                                                                                                                                                   

    def test_profile(self):                                                                                    
        profile = get_user_model().objects.last().profile
```

Comment: @HarryMoreno thank you for the inclusion of the example.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` if the user doesn't exist yet an IntegrityError exception will be thrown since no user_id to be found. The signals will listen when the user will be created not the reverse.
In your testcase `Profile.objects.create()` will try to create a One-To-One relation with a user that doesn't exist.